# amdgpu RX580 on debian: How to stop monitor from switching on and off?

Tags: debian, amd-graphics-card

I have a new system with a new installation of Debian Bullseye.  The graphics card is an RX580 with one monitor connected to the HDMI port and another monitor of a different type connected to the DVI port.

The symptoms are:

- Both monitors turn on and off at the same time, but at random times.
- At that time dmesg says:

> ```
> [50058.208354] [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).
> [50058.305808] [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.
> [50058.456790] [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
> [50066.534370] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: 00000000f84d05e5 unpin not necessary
> [50066.534386] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: 00000000f84d05e5 unpin not necessary
> ```

- Pressing CTRL+ALT+Fn to switch virtual terminals turns the monitor on.  Pressing other keys do not.

The graphics driver is amdgpu.

I am using the kernel parameter "amdgpu.dc=0" because it made dual monitors work.

I first noticed the problem after enabling the front audio ports with pavucontrol-qt.  I'm not sure if this issue could be related to HDMI audio, or if it's a coincidence because the symptoms are random.  Occasionally I have seen unexplained audio popup messages in KDE, but this does not happen often enough for me to tell if it is related.

I'm pretty sure it's not a screensaver or energy management.

How do I get my monitors to stay on?

Comment: off topic This problem went away spontaneously. Apparently, the solution is to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away spontaneously.  Apparently, the solution is to do nothing.